How to properly put an actuator
I have a simple thing that needs to have a robotic arm. Below is the illustration of how it would be.

I'm using Blender style to draw bones (armatures). This is the slice of the thing from right side, consider vertical is Z axis and horizontal is X axis, the red thing is the arm I want to connect the actuator to. In order for the arm to rotate along X axis from the point which placed near B, where should I put a linear actuator in the line between point A and point B? Will the actuator be connected to the arm's endpoint?

what is the red object? ... how is it connected? ... please edit your post ... do not write a comment

i will write a comment. the red things is the arm.

which end is attached to the base?

if you mean base is the thing, then the end is the point of the arm that is touching the line. if you mean base is ground surface, then the end is the point of the arm that isn't touching the line.
